# fetch only first row using mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, left-join

I got 2 tables

**stories**

```
id  |  Story Name   | User id
----+---------------+-----------
2   |  Name         |  12
3   |  Name         |  13
4   |  Name         |  12
5   |  Name         |  12
--------------------------------
```

**lines**

```
id  |  Story Line   | story_id |  started_date
----+---------------+----------+------------------------
2   |  Name         |  2       |  2017-02-17 18:20:14
3   |  Name         |  2       |  2017-02-18 18:20:14
4   |  Name         |  3       |  2017-02-18 18:20:14
5   |  Name         |  2       |  2017-02-19 18:20:14
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to get the first row from the lines table ( ASC of started_date) along with the stories table

```
SELECT story.* from stories as story WHERE story.id=2
```

Using left join

```
SELECT story.* 
from stories as story 
LEFT JOIN lines as line 
ON lines.story_id=story.id
WHERE story.id=2
```

Here how to get the first entry from lines table ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `ORDER BY` combined with `LIMIT` here.  In this case, we want to order ascending (the default order in MySQL) by the `started_date` from the `lines` table, while retaining only a single record, corresponding to the first as you defined it.

```
SELECT story.*, line.*
FROM stories AS story 
LEFT JOIN lines AS line 
    ON lines.story_id = story.id
WHERE story.id=2
ORDER BY lines.started_date
LIMIT 1
```

If you wanted to get the earliest record for all stories, you would have to use a subquery for that:

```
SELECT s.*, l1.*
FROM stories AS s
LEFT JOIN lines l1
    ON s.story_id = l1.story_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT story_id, MIN(started_date) AS first_date
    FROM lines
    GROUP BY story_id
) AS l2
    ON l1.story_id     = l2.story_id AND
       l1.started_date = l2.first_date
```

Comment: nice! then I wondered why was the request just first entry XD

Comment: thanks for your answer. What if I need to ORDER BY story table too ( like ORDER BY story.id ASC) then two ORDER BY will works ?

Comment: like I need to get 10 stories and its first lines

Comment: @ramesh Check my second query.  We can use a subquery to identify the first lines for each story, and then join using this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT story.* 
from stories as s
LEFT JOIN lines as l
ON lines.story_id=story.id
WHERE story.id=2
ORDER BY s.started_date ASC
LIMIT 1
```